# How to extract a sample from a large numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large data set stored as a 300000x860 numpy array and performing any operations on it takes a very long time. Is there any way to extract the first 10000 elements of the numpy array without looping through the first 10000 elements and appending each to a new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what numpy indexing is for:

```
x.shape # gives (300000, 860) 
first_k = x[:10000,:]
```

This would extract the first 10000 rows from the array, but I am not sure what you mean by first 10000 elements since you have a 2D array.

The first 10000 elements would be:

```
ex_rows = np.floor(10000 / cols)
ex_cols = 10000 % cols 
ex_array = old_array[:ex_rows, :ex_cols]
```